# How to create subdomain to post 3-4 .aspx pages in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, subdomain

I am new in asp.net 2.0 My question: I created one asp.net website and hosted it by getting domain and one of my client ask me to post his 3-4 asp.net pages as a sub domain of my main domain, so can anybody expain what to do and if there is any coding please expain me in detail.

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
s.venkatesh.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs on serverfault, just want to say though that there is no coding involved, you just use your provider's dashboard (or IIS if you have access to the server itself) to create a subdomain.